# Internet Explorer 11 and javascript Date.toLocaleDateString() produces hidden characters

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

**Software and versioning:**

**IE11**

**Windows 10 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1110)**

So I found something interesting when working in IE11 related to the call to `Date.toLocaleDateString`, I wanted to post this as I couldn't find anything like this on SO or on the internet for that matter. Take for example this:

Create a new Date object using the constructor `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)` and then call `.toLocaleDateString()`, in my case I am passing in a format of "en-US", so `new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US");` for the date of February 1, 2021 at midnight with 0 minutes, 0 seconds, 0 milliseconds.

Now if I do `new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US").length;` I get 13 instead of the expected "2/1/2021" length of 8. So, what is going on here??

Comment: Whoever decided to down vote this, you want to share why? It's not possible to improve the post without proper feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer by taking the string returned in IE11 from `new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US")` and pasting it into the console window of Chrome. It showed these little dots on the left and right side of the month and day and year values.
[image]

What I found was that these are left to right mark characters or LRM for short, which aren't visible when displayed in the console window of Internet Explorer. Thanks Internet Explorer!

To get the expected result when comparing to a string value representing the same date but not fed through the call to `new Date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")`, I had to chain a call to `.replace()` on the end to get rid of the hidden LRM characters, so in short, to fix this, use:
`new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US").replace(/&lrm;|\u200E/gi, "")`.

Now this comparison works in IE11: `new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US").replace(/&lrm;|\u200E/gi, "") === "2/1/2021";` and produces true but this comparison does not work: `new Date(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US") === "2/1/2021";`
and produces false.

This isn't an issue in Edge, Chrome or Firefox as far as I can tell. Anyway, if anyone gets frustrated by this like I did, perhaps this post will help eleviate the time to understand the issue.